# how to a return a vector<T> from v8 c++ function

Tags: javascript, c++, v8

```
struct empDetails {
int empId;
string name;
};

v8::Handle<v8::Value> GetEMPDetails(const v8::Arguments &args)
{  
    std::vector<empDetails>  e1;
    e1.push_back(empDetails(23, "paul"));
    e1.push_back(empDetails(45, "john")); 

    // how can I return V8 handle so that I can use this vector in 
    // my javascript module
    return e1; 
}
```

here I wanna return e1 to javascript module, could someone please let me know how to do this?

Comment: What problem are you getting?

Comment: I would like to know which data type has to be used here, for structure -> object Template has to be used, but for vector I dont know what data type to use, if you know any page which explains this please let me know..

Comment: could someone pls update a example of how to return a vector in v8...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `v8::Array`, e.g:

```
v8::Handle<v8::Array> result = v8::Array::New(e1.size());
for (size_t i = 0; i < e1.size(); i++)
  result->Set(i, someObject);
```

Obviously you still need to convert your `empDetails` instance to `v8::Object` for each entry in the vector.

Comment: What is `someObject`? @Ariya Hidayat